# Click on a button and a QPixmap appears, click on the same button and QPIxmap disappears

Tags: qt

I am trying to be able to click on a button and have a Pixmap image that I'm using pop up, and when I click the button again, it disappears. Right now when I run my app, the image is already there and when I click the button it disappears. How to fix??

```
#include "yes.h"
#include "ui_yes.h"

yes::yes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::yes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

yes::~yes()
{
    delete ui;
}

void yes::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    hide();
}

void yes::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QPixmap popup("qrc:/new/prefix1/Popover for seat help");
    ui->label->setPixmap(popup);
}
```

Looking at the on_pushButton_clicked()

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just make the popup invisible and then set the visibility to the opposite of whatever it already is with the button click.

```
#include "yes.h"
#include "ui_yes.h"

yes::yes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::yes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setVisible(false);
}

yes::~yes()
{
    delete ui;
}

void yes::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    hide();
}

void yes::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QPixmap popup("qrc:/new/prefix1/Popover for seat help");
   // ui->label->setPixmap(popup);
    ui->label->setVisible(!ui->label->isVisible());
}
```